# If duplicate URL entry exists don't append the data (BeautifulSoup to Google Sheets)

Tags: python, google-sheets, beautifulsoup, google-sheets-api, gspread

I was wondering if you can help.

I'm using beautifulsoup to write to Google Sheets.

I've created a crawler that runs through a series of URLs, scrapes the content and then updates a Google sheet.

What I now want to do is if a duplicate URL exists (in column c) to prevent it from being written to my sheet again.

e.g If I had the url https://www.bbc.co.uk/1 in my table I wouldn't want it appearing in my table again.

Here is my code:

```
from cgitb import text
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import gspread
import datetime
import urllib.parse

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open('scrapetosheets').sheet1

urls = ["https://www.ig.com/uk/trading-strategies", "https://www.ig.com/us/trading-strategies"]

for url in urls:
    my_url = requests.get(url)
    html = my_url.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    for item in soup.find_all('h3', class_="article-category-section-title"):
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        title = item.find('a', class_ = 'primary js_target').text.strip()
        url = item.find('a', class_ = 'primary js_target').get('href')

        abs = "https://www.ig.com"
        rel = url
    
        info = {'date':date, 'title':title, 'url':urllib.parse.urljoin(abs, rel)}
        sh.append_row([str(info['date']), str(info['title']), str(info['url'])])
```

Thanks in advance.

Mark

I'd like to know what i can add to the end of my code to prevent duplicate URLs being entered into my Google Sheet.

Comment: First get all of column c and check if the current url is present there.

Comment: @TheMaster thank you. Im new to python. How would you do that>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to put the values of `[str(info['date']), str(info['title']), str(info['url'])]`, when the value of `str(info['url'])` is not existing in the column "C".

#### Modification points:

- In this case, it is required to check the column "C" of the existing sheet of `sh = gc.open('scrapetosheets').sheet1`. This has already been mentioned in [the TheMaster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74294865/if-duplicate-url-entry-exists-dont-append-the-data-beautifulsoup-to-google-she#comment131165249_74294865).
- When I saw your script, `append_row` is used in a loop. In this case, the process cost will become high.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```py
from cgitb import text
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import gspread
import datetime
import urllib.parse

gc = gspread.service_account(filename='creds.json')
sh = gc.open('scrapetosheets').sheet1

urls = ["https://www.ig.com/uk/trading-strategies", "https://www.ig.com/us/trading-strategies"]

# I modified the below script.
obj = {r[2]: True for r in sh.get_all_values()}
ar = []

for url in urls:
    my_url = requests.get(url)
    html = my_url.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for item in soup.find_all("h3", class_="article-category-section-title"):
        date = datetime.datetime.now()
        title = item.find("a", class_="primary js_target").text.strip()
        url = item.find("a", class_="primary js_target").get("href")
        abs = "https://www.ig.com"
        rel = url
        info = {"date": date, "title": title, "url": urllib.parse.urljoin(abs, rel)}
        url = str(info["url"])
        if url not in obj:
            ar.append([str(info["date"]), str(info["title"]), url])

if ar != []:
    sh.append_rows(ar, value_input_option="USER_ENTERED")
```

- When this script is run, first, the values are retrieved from the sheet, and create an object for searching the value of `str(info["url"])`. When the value of `str(info["url"])` is not existing in column "C" of the sheet, the values are put into an array. And then, the array is appended to the sheet.

#### Reference:

- [append_rows](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api/models/worksheet.html?highlight=append_rows#gspread.worksheet.Worksheet.append_rows)

Comment: @Mark Leach Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.